# iPhone debugging: variables are not up to date?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

I've only recently began using the debugger extensively, so I'm not sure if this is a limitation.

When I debug on the iPhone, the variables aren't up to date unless I explicitly view it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> -> <kbd>view variable as expression</kbd>). Is there a way to view actual variables without viewing explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify your question?  You should only be viewing data while the program is stopped -- examining data while it's running, if it works at all, is much less useful.  Make sure to set a breakpoint, and then examine data once you've hit the breakpoint.

An alternative to using Xcode's built-in debugging features is to use the gdb console.  Type ⌘-Shift-R, or select "Debugging Console" from the menu to open the console.  Then, you can type commands like:

```
# View a variable
print var
# View this object's member variable
print self->memberVar
# Ask an Objective-C object to print itself:
print-object self
```

You should use `print` with primitive types (`int`, `char*`, etc.) and POD types (structs); you should use `print-object` with Objective-C objects (`NSString`, etc.).  For more information about `print` and `print-object`, type

```
help print
help print-object
```

You can also use the abbreviations `p` and `po` for `print` and `print-object` respectively.

Comment: I was not aware of the console features you mentioned. Thank you. 

Clarification: I can see the variables but they don't reflect the current values. My breakpoint is set to pause when objects reach a certain position. After a few rounds, the variables still show the values at the beginning.